# Is there any way to email the job status of a Google DataProc job when it fails?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Messing around with Google Composer and DataProc, I have been asked to find a way to get particulars of failed jobs to Ops users with the minimum number of clicks. I found this screen on the DataProc Jobs page:

[image]

And I was wondering if there was a way to send the contents (including the link to the full log file) via email in the event of a job failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [`email_on_failure = True`](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html?#default-arguments) argument in your [`DataProcSparkOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html?#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcSparkOperator).

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping there would be something that would email the actual body of the error (as attached above), but I don't think there is, so your solution will work for me.

Comment: In case there is a cluster maintenance operation (and the scheduler sees no worker hearbeat) the email_on_failure = True will send an email (as the scheduler will mark the task_instance as zombie) even though the underlying dataproc job is still running fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own email function when catch error. Here is my example our sent slack message when job fail.

```
 private void runCommand(String commandName,
                        String[] commandArgs) {

    try (CommandContext commandContext = createCommandContext()) {
        // find and run the command
        SparkCommand command = commandContext.findCommand(commandName);

        checkSparkResource(command.context.sc());
        command.main(commandArgs);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

        String message = "Something wrong~";
        String title = "Run Job on Dataproc:" + commandName + " Fail";
        String text = e.getMessage();

        SlackNotifier.instance()
                     .error(message, title, text);
    }
}
```